# Why do we need the $\epsilon$ here?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm reading *Courant's:* Integral and Differential Calculus, Vol 2.

In the beginning of the chapter on differentiation, he argues that we need a quantity $A$ depending on $x$ but not on $h$ such that:

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=Ah+o(h)=Ah+\epsilon h$$

I guess I understand that $A$ will end up being the $f'$. Doing the following operation:

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=A+\epsilon $$

I guess I can *see* that. Also, he argues that $\epsilon \to 0$. My problem is: Why did he used the $\epsilon$? I can understand all the rest, but I can't guess the need of $\epsilon$ in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$
is not exactly equal to
$f'(x)$,
but get closer and closer to it
as $h \to 0$.

The $\epsilon$
is the error when
the derivative is approximated
by the difference quotient.
This is just giving
that error a name.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: As $h\to 0,\epsilon \to 0$, then the function is the derivative?

Comment: Correct. If the limit exists, the function is said to be differentiable at $x$, and the limit is the derivative. Another way to look at the derivative (which I proved in another answer of mine) is that the line through $(x, f(x))$ with slope $f'(x)$ is the line with smallest error of all the lines passing through the point.